# Can you install Ubuntu on XPS 18

Tags: tablet

Dell has a new 18" tablet. Can you install ubuntu and if so does it support all of the necessary elements like touch?

Answer (score 2):

Well, It seems like Ubuntu generally worked when run from a 13.04 x64 Live CD. The exceptions I noticed are:

1. No touch
2. The provided wireless keyboard (or mouse) did not work probably since this is the Logitech Unifying driver, not some generic bluetooth type.
3. Issues with Enter key on generic USB keyboard - wasn't activating the Dash contents.

I didn't try a USB mouse, since I ran out of USB ports. I would imagine it would work, and is critical without touch support.

I could not wipe the drive as it was a gift for someone else.  I'm hoping to investigate further permitting access to the device and some research into what kind of screws seal the back plate on. (they are some type of star shape).

Comment: "they are some type of star shape" Search web for Torx and Pozidrive. Wikipedia shows nice pictures [Torx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torx) and [Pozidrive and others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pozidrive#Pozidrive)

Comment: I know this post is ridiculously old, but could you update as to whether you could get the touch screen working eventually?  Thanks.